# Medoo WHERE clause multiple conditions

Tags: php, where-clause, medoo

1. How to write this sql query in medoo?

   ```
   select * from users where name='John' and age=35?
   ```

I tried it like,

```
select('users','*',["AND"=>["name[=]"=>"John","age[=]"=>35]]);
```

2. The above query returns an array when data is found and returns a boolean value instead of an empty array when no such record exists.

Can someone please explain the reason for this?

Comment: add `print_r($database->error());` and `print $database->last_query();` and check the errors.

Comment: Thank you! I found the error (I had misspelt a column name)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple:
It's more easy to use when you want to check if the query returns data before continuing.
For example:

```
if ($myquery) {
    return $myquery;
} else {
    return "no data was returned from 'myquery'";
}
```